# How to connect to mssql database in linux with GO

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, go

I have created and connected to an sql server on linux using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-connect-and-query-sqlcmd) tutorial.

I am using golang and [this](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb) driver. (https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb)

I am having problems connecting to the database using golang. I have specified a user as SA and a password. I have also written in the terminal "hostname" and got the hostname xxx. When I use that info to connect I get a 500 error.

```
conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", "server=xxx; id=SA; password=mypass; database=testdb)
```

Does this seem correct? I am a newbie so maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: are you able to connect from sqlcmd atleast ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar yes I am

Comment: can you show the errorlog contents? `cat /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog` if the connection went through, you might see an entry there.

Comment: I guess 500 error means database access happens inside an http handler. Which would mean your handler's code actually panicked. Recover from panic and log the error intercepted. It will most likely tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having troubles creating a connection string, then you can always get your library to format your connection string for you.

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    // OTHER STUFF
)

func main() {
    cfg := mysql.Config{
        User:   "username",
        Passwd: "password",
        Net:    "tcp",
        Addr:   "127.0.0.1:3306",
        DBName: "database_name",
    }

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", cfg.FormatDSN())
    check(err)

    // DO SOMETHING WITH db
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Github example](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.go) you can see how it work.
You can follow those steps:

```
var (
    server    string = "localhost" // for example
    user      string = "userdb"    // Database user
    password  string = "userpwd"   // User Password
    port      int    = 1433        // Database port
)

connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d", server, user, password, port)
conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)

// Test if the connection is OK or not
if err != nil {
    panic("Cannot connect to database")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Connected!")

  }
// Don't forget to close the connection to your database
defer conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")
```

As simple as this you can connect to your DB
you should add driver in your code as unused package then it has parameters URI to connect to DB.
And you can query like this link blow
https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_Query